# Absolute div with fixed behavior on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I'm trying to have a really long table with an absolute `<thead>` which stays fixed to the bottom of the page header when scrolling. I cannot use position fixed because of the length of the table. When I use position fixed it cant be scrolled. How do I use absolute positioning and make it sticky with javascript/ Jquery?

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var sticky = $('#head');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var Lscroll = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var table =  $('#buget-table').width()

if (scroll >= 150){ 
alert('dd');
    sticky.addClass('fixed'); 
} else {
    sticky.removeClass('fixed'); 
}
});
```

```css
.fixed{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    top:93px;
    background-color: white;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead id="head" >
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="26">
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="vm.clearData()" tooltip="Delete existing data"><i class="fa fa-linux" /></button>
                                <button class="btn" type="button" st-reset-search><i class="fa fa-filter" /> Clear</button>
                                <button class="btn" type="button" ng-csv="vm.budgetState.displayed"><i class="fa fa-save" /> Export</button>
                                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"
                                   title="Some data has changed. Press save to save the changes to the server!"
                                   ng-show="vm.budgetState.isDirty"></i>
                                <button class="btn" ng-click="vm.save()" ng-disabled="!vm.canSave()">Save</button>
                                <button class="btn" ng-click="vm.cancel(true)" ng-disabled="!vm.canSave()">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="uhT2Code"><abbr title="Scheme">UH T2</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="schemeCode"><abbr title="Sun T2">Default Analysis</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="estateCode"><abbr title="Analysis Code">Estate Code</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="propertyRef">Prop Ref</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="nominalCode">Nominal Code</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="nominalDesc">Nominal Description</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="amount">Amount</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="date">Invoice Date</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="reference">Invoice No</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="description">Invoice Description</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="supplierDesc">Supplier Name</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="caseVisionRef"><abbr title="T9">Case Vision Ref</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="worksOrderRef"><abbr title="T8">WO Ref</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="periodDesc">Sun Period</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="budgetHolder"><abbr title="T10">Budget Holder</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="businessActivity"><abbr title="T1">Business Stream</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="propType">Property Type</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="housingOfficer"><abbr title="Property Manager / Housing Officer">PM/HO</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="userName">SC Patch</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="s20ViolationWarning"><abbr title="Flag set if an equal split would be higher than the configured S20 limit">S20 Warning</abbr></th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="s20BViolation">Previous Year</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="isNewCost">New Cost</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="statusString">Status</th>
                        <th class="budget-table-header" st-sort="lastNoteText">Latest Note</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <!--<th st-sort="tenure" ng-show="false">Tenure</th>-->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><input st-search="uhT2Code" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-t2code" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="schemeCode" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="estateCode" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-estatecode" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="propertyRef" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-propertyRef" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="nominalCode" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-nomcode" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input  st-search="nominalDesc" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-nomdesc" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="amount" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-amount" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><st-date-range predicate="date" before="query.before" after="query.after" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="reference" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-reference" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="description" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-description" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="supplierDesc" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="caseVisionRef" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-casevisionref" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="worksOrderRef" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="periodDesc" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-sunperioddesc" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="budgetHolder" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-budgetholder" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="businessActivity" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="propType" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="housingOfficer" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-housingofficer" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="userName" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-username " type="search" /></th>
                        <th><st-select-distinct style-class="input-sm form-control" collection="vm.budgetState.actualTransactions" predicate="s20ViolationWarning" /></th>
                        <th><st-select-distinct style-class="input-sm form-control" collection="vm.budgetState.actualTransactions" predicate="s20BViolation" /></th>
                        <th><st-select-distinct style-class="input-sm form-control" collection="vm.budgetState.actualTransactions" predicate="isNewCost" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="statusString" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="lastNoteText" class="input-sm form-control latestNote" type="search" /></th>
                        <th><input class="input-sm form-control latestNote" type="search" disabled /></th>
                        <!--<th ng-show="false"><input st-search="tenure" class="input-sm form-control budget-table-tenure" type="search" /></th>-->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: code? I can't see any code in your question!

Comment: I have some code but it a complete mess, I've just been trying different things.

Comment: please, add all your codes, `html` & `css` & `js`

Comment: well, first problem is you not defined what `sticky` is,  sticky not defined. sticky is `#head` ? / `scroll` too. or you not included your whole code

Comment: I added the variables now sorry.

Comment: no problem, I also added `$(window).scroll(function() {});` without this function your code not working.

Comment: well looks like there is no more error, now i need to know what are trying to do exactly, still not following you.

Comment: I want to fix the thead to the top of the page using absolute positioning when scrolling. I can't use position fixed because its too long.